# Creating KML superoverlays with gdal2tiles

Tags: kml, google-earth, gdal

I am trying to use `gdal2tiles` to batch-create a bunch of KML superoverlays from a set big geotiff files; problem is that the `gdal2tiles` output seems to be stripped of its lowest-values point (i.e. the blue ones in the first image below)

This is an example of a superoverlay created directly from Google Earth Pro (using its built-in function):

[image]

This is the corresponding output of `gdal2tiles`, which I generated following the instructions explained in [this](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster) KML guide; particularly, this is what I did:

```
gdalwarp -of VRT -t_srs EPSG:4326 input.tif output.vrt
gdal2tiles.py -p geodetic -k output.vrt outputdir/
```

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? Any suggestions on how to avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: Are the NoData values in input.tif and output.vrt the same? Are all the blue pixels of the same low value, e.g. 0?